# Click an Item -hold- and swipe to an other site

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

If an object is clicked, the next page should not be called immediately. But the click should remain on the object until you scroll through a wipe to the next page.

How can it hold the click command on an Item?

How can it swipe from the clicked Item to an other Page?

**Update**

Click one item > OnHold> swipe from the holded item to the left and right.

This is the actual behavior:

```
    private int index = -1;

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight the item when it is clicked, you can set background color to the item's view, to perform a swipe gesture for each item, I think you will need to implement `IOnTouchListener` for each item. Here I created an adapter to implement this feature:

```cs
public class LVAdapter : BaseAdapter<ListItemModel>, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private List<ListItemModel> items = new List<ListItemModel>();
    private Activity context;

    private int index = -1;

    public enum SwipeAction
    {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to Top
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    private int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private SwipeAction maction = SwipeAction.None;

    public LVAdapter(Activity context, List<ListItemModel> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override ListItemModel this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    private void SetSelectedItem(int position)
    {
        index = position;
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MyViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView Name { get; set; }
        public TextView Description { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        var view = convertView;

        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as MyViewHolder;

        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new MyViewHolder();
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemCell, null);
            holder.Name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nametxt);
            holder.Description = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailtxt);
            holder.index = position;
            view.Tag = holder;
        }

        holder.Name.Text = items[position].Name;
        holder.Description.Text = items[position].Description;

        if (index != -1 && position == index)
        {
            holder.Name.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
            holder.Description.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Pink);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.Name.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.RoyalBlue);
            holder.Description.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.SeaGreen);
        }

        view.SetOnTouchListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                downX = e.GetX();
                downY = e.GetY();
                maction = SwipeAction.None;
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                upX = e.GetX();
                upY = e.GetY();
                var deltaX = downX - upX;
                var deltaY = downY - upY;

                if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                {
                    if (deltaX < 0)
                    {
                        maction = SwipeAction.LR;
                    }
                    else if (deltaX > 0)
                    {
                        maction = SwipeAction.RL;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (Math.Abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                {
                    if (deltaY < 0)
                    {
                        maction = SwipeAction.TB;
                    }
                    else if (deltaY > 0)
                    {
                        maction = SwipeAction.BT;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                var holder = v.Tag as MyViewHolder;
                if (maction == SwipeAction.None)
                {
                    SetSelectedItem(holder.index);
                }
                else if (maction == SwipeAction.LR | maction == SwipeAction.RL)
                {
                    if (holder.index == index)
                        context.StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `ListItemModel` is quite simple by my side:

```cs
public class ListItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You can try to modify the model and holder as you need.

[image]

Comment: @My_yz, did you tried my code? That should have the same behavior.

Comment: @My_yz, then they must be in one activity. I started a new activity.

Comment: @My_yz, not that simple, if they are in the same activity, the layout should be changed, maybe it's a `ViewPager` or something else.  The gesture problem is solved in this answer. Then maybe you need to post a new thread ask about this layout.

Comment: @My_yz, how to say...The important thing is that it's a horizontal scroll-able layout, I didn't try it, but I think if using `ViewPager`, then the listview should placed in one time, and in other item show your details.